# Where is `HOST` being set to `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0`

Tags: zsh, hosts

This is the last line of my `.zshrc`:

```
export HOST="localhost"
```

How is this happening?

```
❯ source ~/.zshrc
❯ echo $HOST
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
```

Comment: Maybe from a `precmd` or something similar? `add-zsh-hook -L` will list the current hook functions.

Comment: @gairfowl. Nailed it! Thank you.

`add-zsh-hook -L` reveals this is being run: `_conda_clang_preexec`, which contains this: `HOST="${CONDA_TOOLCHAIN_HOST}"`. If I `echo $CONDA_TOOLCHAIN_HOST`, sure enough it is `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0`

Comment: Is `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0` actually the name of your Mac (what does `/bin/hostname` say)?

Comment: @nohillside no, but apparently conda sets it that way for some reason

Answer (score -1):

The value of the `HOST` parameter is automatically set to the output of `hostname(1)`. See the `zshparam` man page.

Comment: But it seems that it can be overwritten (I just tried to set it manually and the new value was assigned).